# PostgreSQL PostGIS geopoint within angle range

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm new to PostGIS and I see there are so many options, it's a bit overwhelming.

I want to simply find all geo points (stored in [ISO 6709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709) format) within a certain angle of a given geopoint.

For example, given a geopoint "+25 -90", find all geopoints within 5degrees angle of that geo point, that is:

- +25+/-5 degrees -> 20 to 30 degrees latitude
- -90+/-5 degrees -> -85 to -95 degrees longitude

What's the easiest way to achieve this query?

Thanks

Comment: ISO 3166 doesn't specify a format to store geographical points. Perhaps you're confusing ISO and a different spec for EPSG?

Comment: I mean the Geo point are in ISO 3166 format (i.e. the string format), then obviously I would need to convert that to a 'geography' or 'geometry' in PostGIS I guess

Comment: ISO 3166 doesn't specify a string format for points. If it does, please provide that part of the spec in your answer or a link.

Comment: my bad, I meant ISO 6709.

Comment: just found this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84108/how-to-check-if-points-are-within-a-circular-sector-using-postgis which seems like a reasonable answer.

Comment: Could you paste some of the examples that you want to pass and fail your test (5 degrees)?

Comment: +/-5 degrees on each direction, which represents a 'rectangle' on a flattened map of the earth. I'm pretty sure there must be a function for that.

Comment: I'm looking for a latitude and longitude coordinate, three points that pass (within 5 degrees), three points that fail (more than five degrees) in your desired format. Then I'll write the code to do what you want (if I can). Then I'll check against your test case.

Comment: Is this the formula: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545955/3270427?